Does Azure free student subscription require you to provide credit card details to start using?
I have opted for a student subscription with free 100$ credits in azure. While trying to create a workspace, it says

The subscription '46024215-4eb0-4318-8616-865966d1e706' is disabled and therefore marked as read only. You cannot perform any write actions on this subscription until it is re-enabled. (Code: ReadOnlyDisabledSubscription)

How can I start using the free credits in my subscription? Do I have to provide credit card details even if I have free credits through the student pass?

Accordingly to Microsoft's documentation

A credit card is not required for the Azure for Students offer. You
may upgrade to a Pay-As-You-Go subscription by contacting Azure
Support.

However, as per your message, it seems that either your credit is exhausted and now your Subscription is as "Read Only" or your credits expired due to 12 months limit
It's important to mention that with Azure for Students, eligible customers receive $100 in credits, which can be used within 12 months on most Azure products. Any unused credits cannot be carried over to subsequent months and cannot be transferred to other Azure subscriptions.
If you exhaust your available credits, your Azure subscription will be disabled. You may then upgrade to a Pay-As-You-Go subscription by contacting Azure Support. This allows continued use of Azure.

Looks like the issue was with having a previous free credit pass. Earlier one expired last year and this new student pass was disabled since I already used up 100$ for earlier pass.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/azurestudents-subscription-disabled?WT.mc_id=AzureStudentsOffer
